# Upgrade and SonarQube not listening on network

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Upgraded from 5.6 to 6.1. Sonar.properties are, and they match what was there before:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://10.120.8.27:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.web.host=10.120.8.27
sonar.web.context=/sonar
sonar.web.port=9000
```

SonarQube starts and is running but it's not listening on port 9000. OS is CentOS 6.6, SElinux disabled. I can find no errors in the logs, indeed sonar.log has no entries at all. What have I missed?

```
ps -ef|grep sonar

sonar     1325     1  0 12:06 ?        00:00:00
/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper
/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/../../conf/wrapper.conf
wrapper.syslog.ident=SonarQube
wrapper.pidfile=/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/./SonarQube.pid
wrapper.daemonize=TRUE

sonar     1327  1325  2 12:06 ?        00:00:25 java
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms3m -Xmx3m -Djava.library.path=./lib -classpath
../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-6.1.jar
-Dwrapper.key=byv_fqDBq6Ok__mi -Dwrapper.port=32000
-Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
-Dwrapper.debug=TRUE -Dwrapper.pid=1325 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
-Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
-Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.sonar.application.App

sonar     1545  1327 99 12:06 ?        00:24:20
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-0.b15.el6_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true
-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp
-javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-0.b15.el6_8.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
-cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer
/opt/sonar/temp/sq-process7944098912777335007properties
```

Comment: You should investigate why logs are empty. That's not the expected behaviour. The file logs/sonar.log is created at startup. Can you try to kill the 3 processes, delete the file and restart ?

Comment: Moreover how did you install the new version 6.1 ? Did you correctly unzip in a fresh directory and not over the existing 5.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Was a permissions problem on the logs. From there log tracing lead to other, but clear problems.